# How to bind two models in __init__ via related_name when calling only parent, creating an empty object

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

I have two models, as below, linked by the OneToOneField relationship. How can I check by related_name
that there is a link to x.RelName before I use x.save (). Everything below ...

**models.py**

```
class Parent(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
     member = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="MemberUsr", blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Child(models.Model):
     child_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
     parent_name = models.OneToOneField(Parent, related_name='RelName', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**py manage.py shell**

```
>>> from app1.models import Parent, Child

>>> x = Parent()
```

And at this point there should be an artificial connection in **_ _ init _ _**

```
>>> x.RelName
```

Should return that it is artificially bound to Child. If I run x.save () it obviously creates linkages.
But I would like to be able to check with related_name before save () that there is a binding.

**Update**
**Solution**

```
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        cls = self.__class__
        cls_child = cls._meta.get_field('RelName').related_model
        self.RelName = cls_child(self)


    def save(self, **kwargs):
        super().save(**kwargs)
        cls = self.__class__
        cls_child = cls._meta.get_field('RelName').related_model

        RelName = cls_child(parent_name=self)
        RelName.save()
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'link'? Let me see if I uderstood, do you want to verify id parent exist before saver()?

Comment: I want to check if the child exists connected to the parent before using save ()
Now when I check **x.RelName** I get:
```app1.models.Parent.RelName.RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: Parent has no RelName.```

And I would like to get **x.RelName** after typing:
```<Child: NameChild>```

Comment: I don't understand your question, you need to understand that your models are a representation of database tables. So when you say that `Child` has a `OneToOneField` with `Parent`, in database terms it basically means there is a FK from Child to Parent with a unique constraint. What you say is that before the parent is even added to the database there should be a related child existing for it? That is not possible

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think you are misunderstanding the creation of objects. The error that mention you it is because you are not creating the parent instance before.
Check the documentation about [How save objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#saving-objects).

For example, in your case:

```
from app1.models import Parent, Child
parent = Parent(name='Parent example', member= instance_user)     
parent.save() 
child = Child(child_name='Child', parent_name=parent)
child.save()
```

At this moment, you can write verify the relationship `child.RelName`

**Other observation**: you should rename your fields in model `Child`, just named as '`name`' and '`parent`'.

---

**Update:**

The documentation of python:

> You may be tempted to customize the model by overriding the **init**
> method. If you do so, however, take care not to change the calling
> signature as any change may prevent the model instance from being
> saved.

So, you could consider the options here: [creating objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects).

Comment: That's not what I meant by the end. I wanted to have a relationship before **save()**. I must definitely do this somehow in **_ _ init _ _**